# hiding the url directory using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to hide the /watch/ from the following link:

```
url = localhost/main/example.com/watch/web-portfolio/
```

So that it appears like:

```
url = localhost/main/example.com/web-portfolio/
```

I've tried searching through the net but couldnot find the solution. I've tried following:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+watch/
RewriteRule ^watch/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Also tried

```
RewriteRule ^((?!watch/).*)$ watch/$1 [NC,L]
```

And others too but didn't work.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess file?

Comment: .htaccess is in example.com directory @anubhava

Comment: You mean it's in `/main/example.com/.htaccess` file? If yes then what happens when you enter: `localhost/main/example.com/web-portfolio/` in browser?

Comment: @anubhava Yes .htaccess file is in localhost/main/example.com/.htaccess . As I 've tried various code some of them gave internal error while some codes have no effect at all

Comment: ok but you have shown one rule in question. Better you create a new question and post full .htaccess. Also add what's working and what's not.